# Using perl to selectively change lines

Tags: perl

Trying to selectively change all line in a file with many other lines.

input:

```
    abc  
    PASSWORD=123  
    xyz
```

desired output;

```
    abc
    PASSWORD *redacted*
    xyz
```

Here is the perl one-liner I am using.  I have tried a few variations on it, but results are not as desired.

```
perl -i.bak  -pe '{if (/PASSWORD/) {print  "PASSWORD *redacted*"}else {print "$_"}}' yme.conf
```

(note the -i.bak is necessary on Solaris).

What I get from that script is:

```
    abc
    abc
    PASSWORD=*redacted*   PASSWORD=123
    xyz
    xyz
```

I have many files to do here (*.conf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting extra output because the `-p` option already prints `$_` automatically. You can fix your original code by using `-n` instead (and adding `\n` to the redacted string):

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'if (/PASSWORD/) {print "PASSWORD *redacted*\n"} else {print $_}' yme.conf
```

This can be simplified by using `-p`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'if (/PASSWORD/) {$_ = "PASSWORD *redacted*\n"}' yme.conf
```

We loop over the input lines, with the current line being stored in `$_`. If it contains `PASSWORD`, we overwrite it. The `-p` option automatically outputs `$_` at the end of the loop, which is then either the original line or our redacted version.

Answer (score 4):

Since `-p` means print, there is no reason to use `print` again.  The following uses the substitution operator to replace everything after the word `PASSWORD` with `*redacted*`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(PASSWORD).*/$1 *redacted*/' yme.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

$variable =~ s/PASSWORD/PASSWORD *redacted*/g;

This will change the desired line globally.